# Spark "java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number" in docker when run through Jenkins

Tags: python, apache-spark, docker, jenkins, pyspark

I'm creating a dockerfile with java 8 and spark installed, and I'm setting the environment variables as

```
ENV SPARK_HOME=/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7
ENV PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
ENV PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,junit:junit:4.12,org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3 pyspark-shell"
```

When I run my spark job within docker, it works. But when I trigger it via Jenkins,
I get the following error:

```
[pytest]     self.spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
[pytest] /spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:173: in getOrCreate
[pytest]     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
[pytest] /spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py:331: in getOrCreate
[pytest]     SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
[pytest] /spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py:115: in __init__
[pytest]     SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
[pytest] /spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py:280: in _ensure_initialized
[pytest]     SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)

...

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
[pytest] 
[pytest] /spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py:95: Exception
```

I've tried removing the `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` but it doesn't work.
What's causing this?

Comment: It's difficult to say at first glance since it can depend on a lot of stuff: maybe a proxy, maybe missing JAVA_HOME (some possible reasons are listed here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743). I advise you also to take a look at already written Docker image with PySpark. It may give you some clue about why yours doesn't work. You can also test these images locally and after on Jenkins. If it fails on Jenkins and succeeds locally, the problems may come from Jenkins or network configuration. If you fixed the problem, please share the solution. I'm curious about the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be missing a `pyspark-shell` in your `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` definition...

```
ENV PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,junit:junit:4.12,org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3 pyspark-shell"
```